# Google Analytics Total Events vs Unique Events discrepancy, how to?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I am tracking a button click on some pages, and there seems to be an issue.

The Total Events are way too high, I don't think people are clicking on it that many times.

I can see that Unique Events are 0 when Total Events are 98, and that's not possible.. would need to be at least 1 Unique vent

Any ideas what's happening or how to better track these stats?

Should I exclude all numbers if the Unique Events > 0 (at least one session) ?

[image]

Comment: Which version of GA are you using?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller  Not GA4